# $Var[W]$ when $W = X - 2Y$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance, expected-value

I am trying to solve $Var[W]$ when $W = X - 2Y$ for independent discrete RVs $X$ & $Y$:

> $$E[X] = 9, Var[X] = 4; E[Y] = 2, Var[Y] = 1.$$

I understand

> $$ Var[W] = Var[X] + Var[2Y]$$
>   $$= Var[X] + 4Var[Y]$$
>   $$ = 4 + 4*1 = 8$$

But I am trying to answer the same using:

> $$ Var[W] = E[W^2] - E[W]^2$$

I think

> $$E[W] = 1 \implies E[W]^2 = 1$$

But when I calculate

> $$ E[(X-2Y)^2] = E[X^2 - 4XY + 4Y^2]$$
>   $$ =  E[X^2] - 4E[X]E[Y] + 4[Y^2]$$
>   $$ = 85 -72 + 20 = 33$$
>   $$ \implies Var[W] = 32$$

Which I don't think is correct.

Where have I gone wrong the second calculation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is $E[W]=1$.  Note that
$$E[W]=E[X-2Y]=E[X]-2E[Y]=9-2\cdot 2=5.$$
The rest is correct except
$$Var(W)=33-5^2=8.$$
Alternatively, use
$$Var(X-2Y)=Var(X)+Var(-2Y)+2Cor(X,-2Y).$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Cor(X,-2Y)=-2Cor(X,Y)=0$.  Hence,
$$Var(X-2Y)=Var(X)+Var(-2Y)=Var(X)+4Var(Y)=4+4\cdot 1=8.$$

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I was multiplying $2^2 * 2$ for $2E[Y]$ for some reason. Late at night I guess. Thanks.